# Include a variable inside a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, string-formatting, string-concatenation

This works fine, we all know that:

```
NSString *textoutput = @"Hello";
outLabel.text = textoutput;
```

However, what if you want to include a variable inside that `NSString` statement like the following:

```
NSString *textoutput =@"Hello" Variable;
```

In C++ I know when I `cout` something and I wanted to include a variable all I did was soemthing like this:

```
cout << "Hello" << variableName << endl;
```

So I'm trying to accomplish that with Objective-C but I don't see how.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do some fancy formatting using the following function:

```
NSString *textoutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", variable];
```

Note that `%@` assumes that `variable` is an Objective-C object. If it's a C string, use `%s`, and if it's any other C type, check out the `printf` reference.

Alternatively, you can create a new string by appending a string to an existing string:

```
NSString *hello = @"Hello";
NSString *whatever = [hello stringByAppendingString:@", world!"];
```

Note that `NSString` is immutable -- once you assign a value, you can't change it, only derive new objects. If you are going to be appending a lot to a string, you should probably use `NSMutableString` instead.

Comment: No problem. We'd be glad if you'd upvote (the upwards triangle) the answers and "accept" one of them (the checkmark); those are the standard ways of expressing gratitude on Stack Overflow. ;-)

Answer (score 7):

I have The Cure you're looking for, Robert Smith:

if your variable is an object, use this:
`NSString *textOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@", Variable];`

The '%@' will only work for objects. For integers, it's '%i'.

For other types, or if you want more specificity over the string it produces, [use this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html)

Comment: @Jordaan hahaa. well played =)